# Can I do Chow Mein without rice wine nor substituting it?

Tags: substitutions, wine, chinese-cuisine, rice-wine

I mistakenly bought "rice wine vinegar" instead of "rice wine". Now I am missing this ingredient from the recipe but I still want to do it. I could replace with red wine but I guess it's not a good substitute. I don't have any of the common substitutes for rice wine (gin, sherry, apple juice...).

Answer (score 2):

I would say, yes, you can make chow mein without wine of any kind. I say that without hesitation because the first four recipes that come up on a Google search for chow mein (all highly rated) don't call for wine.